# What happens when there are less elements in ArrayList than its capacity?

Tags: java, arraylist

Say capacity is 10, I add 5 elements to ArrayList. Would they take 5 or 10 elements size in memory?

Comment: The array is pre-allocated, so 10.

Comment: Interesting, thanks

Comment: Notice: Not the size of 10 objects, but the size of 10 references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) states:

> Each `ArrayList` instance has a *capacity*. The capacity is the size of the array used to store the elements in the list. It is always at least as large as the list size. As elements are added to an `ArrayList`, its capacity grows automatically. The details of the growth policy are not specified beyond the fact that adding an element has constant amortized time cost.

Based on the above:

> What happens when there are less elements in `ArrayList` than its capacity?

Given that the backing array's size is the "capacity", there will be unused slots in the array.

(The implementation ensures that those unused slots contain `null` to avoid any memory leaks.)

> Say capacity is 10, I add 5 elements to `ArrayList`. Would they take 5 or 10 elements size in memory?

The size would be the size of 10 object *references*, since an `ArrayList` holds references to objects ... not the actual element objects themselves.

Comment: Thanks all clear. Does it resize from 10 to 15 or from 10 to 20? I read somewhere it is 1.5 and somewhere it is 2. Kinda confused there :)

Comment: As the javadoc states, the growth policy is **not specified** beyond the fact that adding an element has constant amortized time cost.  But you can find it out when the policy is by reading the source code for the version of Java you are interested in.  I recommend that you start doing that.  (It is better than relying on sources such as "I read somewhere".)

Comment: But you can rely on the "constant amortized time cost" part.  Basically it is saying that appending an element to an array list is `O(1)` on average.

Comment: One more question, hope you can clear it :) You said if I have capacity of 10, but 5 elements in it, other 5 would be stored as null (to prevent memory leak). But if I do list.get(6), I don't get null, I get famous IndexOutOfBoundsException. Why it doesn't return null then?